# Positioning widgets to QBoxLayout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I'm using PySide to build a GUI

I have a QBoxLayout that I have add some Widgets to, the problem is I want control their positions which I was not able to do, I tried what have been provided in the documentation page which is

```
addWidget( widg, int streatch, int alignment)
```

but it is not giving me what I want so the final look that I want is something like this

---

------------------------------------------------------------ ^^ ******
                                                                &&&&&&

if the line ***_*___** represents the whole window/ layout 
I would like the widget which I named `wid` in my code to be like the dashed line --------
and the sliders to be in the same place as ^^
and finally the button to be in &&&&&

My second question is I want to add some labels to the sliders and to the como-box and I would like to determine the position how can I do that

here is my code

```
    self.wid = GLWidget()

    mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.wid)



    self.xSlider = self.createSlider()
    self.ySlider = self.createSlider()

    mainLayout.addWidget(self.xSlider)
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.ySlider)

    self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('OK')
    self.btn.resize(self.btn.sizeHint())

    mainLayout.addWidget(self.btn)


    self.combo = QtGui.QComboBox()

    mainLayout.addWidget(self.combo)

    self.setLayout(mainLayout)
    self.setWindowTitle(self.tr("Hello GL"))
    self.setGeometry(350, 350, 1000, 1000)
```

Comment: Why don't you use Qt Designer?

Comment: @ivica I'm almost done with my implementation and I do not know how to use Qt Designer

Comment: I believe it would be easier to learn how to use it (it's really simple) than to type every layout by hand. It's your choice of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a QGridLayout instead of QHBoxLayout and use QGridLayout's [setColumnMinimumWidth](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QGridLayout.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QGridLayout.setColumnMinimumWidth) method to dictate your required widget width.Like that:

```
mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
mainLayout.setColumnMinimumWidth(0, 100) #set column 0 width to 100 pixels
button = QtGui.QPushButton('OK')
mainLayout.addWidget(button, 0, 0) #adds the button to the widened column
```

and then continue to add the rest of the widgets.

Comment: it is not working it displays the following AttributeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QGridLayout' object has no attribute 'setMinimumColumnWidth'

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong.The method is called actually 'setColumnMinimumWidth'.But it's the library makers fault of course, they should have made it like I first wrote it! :d.